# failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.56.2:5000/v2/ubn_mysql/manifests/latest": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: kubernetes

Warning  Failed     22s (x2 over 37s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "192.168.56.2:5000/ubn_mysql:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "192.168.56.2:5000/ubn_mysql:latest": failed to resolve reference "192.168.56.2:5000/ubn_mysql:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.56.2:5000/v2/ubn_mysql/manifests/latest": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Getting above error while creating pod in k8. I am able to pull this image on worker nodes using
"docker pull 192.168.56.2:5000/ubn_mysql:latest" from registry '**[http://192.168.56.2:5000/ubn_mysql:latest**'](http://192.168.56.2:5000/ubn_mysql:latest**%27) but getting issue while creating pod only.

I already have entries in below files:

vagrant@kubemaster:~/pods_yaml$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{"insecure-registries" : ["192.168.56.2:5000"]}

vagrant@kubemaster:~/pods_yaml$ cat /etc/default/docker
DOCKER_OPTS="--config-file=/etc/docker/daemon.json"